# ConnectionRefusedError in dJango rest api while registration process

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework

ConnectionRefusedError error showing when register user,

basic information added on database but password field was blank and other database fields submitted please find the following error and our class code,

**Class**

class ProfessionalRegistrationSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):

```
password = serializers.CharField(max_length=20, write_only=True)


email = serializers.EmailField()
first_name = serializers.CharField(max_length=30)
last_name = serializers.CharField(max_length=30)

class Meta:
    model = User

    fields = ('url', 'id', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'password')

def validate_email(self, value):
    from validate_email_address import validate_email
    if User.all_objects.filter(email=value.lower()).exists():
        raise serializers.ValidationError('User with this email already exists.')

    return value.lower()

def create(self, validated_data):
    password = validated_data.pop('password')
    email = validated_data.pop('email')
    user = User.objects.create(
        username=email.lower(),
        email=email.lower(),
        role_id=1,
        **validated_data)
    user.set_password(password)

    user.save()

    return user
```

**Error**

ConnectionRefusedError at /api/v1/register/professional/
[Errno 111] Connection refused
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/register/professional/
Django Version: 1.8.14
Exception Type: ConnectionRefusedError
Exception Value:
[Errno 111] Connection refused
Exception Location: /usr/lib/python3.5/socket.py in create_connection, line 702
Python Executable:  /home/project_backend/env/bin/python
Python Version: 3.5.2
Python Path:
['/home/project_backend',
 '/home/project_backend/env/lib/python35.zip',
 '/home/project_backend/env/lib/python3.5',
 '/home/project_backend/env/lib/python3.5/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu',
 '/home/project_backend/env/lib/python3.5/lib-dynload',
 '/usr/lib/python3.5',
 '/usr/lib/python3.5/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu',
 '/home/project_backend/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages',
 '/home/project_backend/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/setuptools-36.0.1-py3.5.egg']

**Traceback**

```
File "/home/project_backend/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
```

132.response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs) File "/home/project_backend/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py" in wrapped_view
  58.         return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
File "/home/project_backend/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py" in view
  71.             return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/home/project_backend/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py" in dispatch
  464.             response = self.handle_exception(exc)
File "/home/project_backend/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py" in dispatch
  461.             response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/home/project_backend/filmup/apps/registrations/views.py" in post
  53.         user = serializer.save(work_status=user_type)
File "/home/project_backend/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py" in save
  175.             self.instance = self.create(validated_data)
File "/home/project_backend/project/apps/registrations/serializers.py" in create
  157.             **validated_data)
File "/home/project_backend/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py" in manager_method
  127.                 return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
File "/home/project_backend/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in create
  348.         obj.save(force_insert=True, using=self.db)
File "/home/project_backend/project/libs/accounts/models.py" in save
  217.         super().save(*args, **kwargs)
File "/home/project_backend/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py" in save
  734.                        force_update=force_update, update_fields=update_fields)
File "/home/project_backend/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py" in save_base
  771.                                    update_fields=update_fields, raw=raw, using=using)
File "/home/project_backend/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/dispatch/dispatcher.py" in send
  189.             response = receiver(signal=self, sender=sender, **named)
File "/home/project_backend/filmup/libs/accounts/signals.py" in create_user_setting
  19.         create_ejabberd_user(instance)
File "/home/project_backend/project/libs/accounts/signals.py" in create_ejabberd_user
  11.     EjabberdUser.objects.create(username=str(user.id), password=str(token.key))
File "/home/project_backend/project/libs/accounts/models.py" in create
  73.         ctl.register(user=kwargs['username'], password=kwargs['password'])
File "/home/project_backend/project/libs/ejabberdctl.py" in register
  54.                                      'password': password})
File "/home/project_backend/project/libs/ejabberdctl.py" in ctl
  32.                 return fn(self.params, payload)
File "/usr/lib/python3.5/xmlrpc/client.py" in **call**
  1092.         return self.__send(self.__name, args)
File "/usr/lib/python3.5/xmlrpc/client.py" in __request
  1432.             verbose=self.__verbose
File "/usr/lib/python3.5/xmlrpc/client.py" in request
  1134.                 return self.single_request(host, handler, request_body, verbose)
File "/usr/lib/python3.5/xmlrpc/client.py" in single_request
  1146.             http_conn = self.send_request(host, handler, request_body, verbose)
File "/usr/lib/python3.5/xmlrpc/client.py" in send_request
  1259.         self.send_content(connection, request_body)
File "/usr/lib/python3.5/xmlrpc/client.py" in send_content
  1289.         connection.endheaders(request_body)
File "/usr/lib/python3.5/http/client.py" in endheaders
  1102.         self._send_output(message_body)
File "/usr/lib/python3.5/http/client.py" in _send_output
  934.         self.send(msg)
File "/usr/lib/python3.5/http/client.py" in send
  877.                 self.connect()
File "/usr/lib/python3.5/http/client.py" in connect
  849.             (self.host,self.port), self.timeout, self.source_address)
File "/usr/lib/python3.5/socket.py" in create_connection
  711.         raise err
File "/usr/lib/python3.5/socket.py" in create_connection
  702.             sock.connect(sa)

Comment: Full traceback would help figure out what's missing here. There's no reason to have this with the code you've shown.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about third party web services that aren't mentioned.

Comment: plz point out which third party api is calling ?

Comment: The traceback is hardly human readable but you can see a couple of "xmlrpc/client.py" which means you're calling a 3rd party XMLRPC server.

Comment: I'm New in Django, i don't know how it is calling.
when i call the registration api on post method then all data was save except password and after 

user = User.objects.create(
            username=email.lower(),
            email=email.lower(),
            role_id=1,
            **validated_data)  this script nothing returns in "user"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You perform a call to a remote server that you can't reach / isn't configured / isn't running.

It's not an issue with Django or DRF.

Comment: would you like to point out where and which part of script calling from remote?

Answer (score 9):

I was getting the same error and it may be due to email verification. I add following code in my setting.py file and now authentication working perfectly

```
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_VERIFICATION = 'none'

ACCOUNT_AUTHENTICATION_METHOD = 'username'

ACCOUNT_EMAIL_REQUIRED = False
```